# JPA/Hibernate: code based validation of jpa queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

What is the right way do validate a jpa query programmatically. Hibernate validates all annotation based named queries on entities. But how can I call this validation routine on programmatically builded jpa queries, to check for errors?

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
@Id
public int id;

public String name;

}
```

```
main(...) {
    Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery("select e from " + Foo.class.getName() + " e where e.name = 'x' ");
    // validate q here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't. Integration test the hell out of your code, using a real database with the same schema as your production environment.

Think about it: if you create a malformed query, that's a *programming bug*. What are you going to do with the information? Tell the user that a JPA query is malformed? All you can realistically do is log the error and tell the user "something bad happened". You'll know it's a malformed query when you check the logs later anyway...

**Edit**

It might also be worth investigating the `createQuery()` call by feeding it bad data - the javadoc [here](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createQuery(java.lang.String)) suggests that it can throw a `HibernateException`, and I'm not sure what it could do with a string other than validate it...

Comment: i just want validate my programmaticly generated queries, just like hibernate does it for @namedquery. If a error is found the program must of course shutdown. Where i do the check is not the question here, the How is.

Comment: @KlausMeier - if you look here: https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createQuery(java.lang.String), you'll see that the createQuery() method can throw an exception. It might well already be validating for you. Feed a broken query in and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use createQuery, or you need to put your class name while writing a JPQL.